# File Upload larger than 57 MB Elastic Beanstalk getting 405 Status - don't get this bug on localhost

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, amazon-s3, file-upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently working on a Web-App, developed with Vue JS and SpringBoot as a multimodular Maven Project.
The Web-App is deployed on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk with SQL-DB and S3-Bucket connection.
I would like to realize a File Upload for Videos (.mp4) into the S3 Bucket. There I am facing the following problem:

- The file upload on localhost works (localhost:XXXX/api/fileUplaodPublicRead) fine for all sizes of files!
- The file upload on the deployed version on Elastic Beanstalk doesn't work for files, which are larger than 57 MB. I got a status 405: Method not allowed.

The mystery is now the following:

- The File Upload works on localhost fine, so I suppose that my Code for uploading files is correct
  (anyway please find attached the code snippet).

```
@Service
public class AmazonClient {

    private AmazonS3 s3client;

    @Value("${aws.endpointUrl}")
    private String endpointUrl;
    @Value("${aws.s3.bucket}")
    private String bucketName;
    @Value("${aws.access_key_id}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${aws.secret_access_key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${aws.s3.region}")
    private String region;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeAmazon() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
        // this.s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        this.s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.fromName(region))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
    }


    public String uploadFilePublicRead(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        String fileUrl = "";
        try {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            
            String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
            uploadFileTos3bucketPublicRead(fileName, file);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileUrl;
    }

    public String uploadMultiPartFilePublicRead(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        String fileUrl = "";
        String fileName= "";
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            
            fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;

           // uploadFileTos3bucketPublicRead(fileName, file);

            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(!file.exists()) return "File does not exits";

        int maxUploadThreads = 5;

        TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder
                .standard()
                .withS3Client(s3client)
                .withMultipartUploadThreshold((long) (5 * 1024 * 1024))
                .withExecutorFactory(() -> Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxUploadThreads))
                .build();

         double size = this.getSizeOfFile(file, 0); 
         
        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength((long) this.getSizeOfFile(file, 0));
    
        

        ProgressListener progressListener =
                progressEvent -> System.out.println("Transferred bytes: " + progressEvent.getBytesTransferred());
          
        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(this.bucketName, fileName, file)
        .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
        .withMetadata(metadata);

      

        request.setGeneralProgressListener(progressListener);

        Upload upload = tm.upload(request);
        
        
        try {
            upload.waitForCompletion();
            System.out.println("Upload complete.");
        } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred while uploading file: AmazonClientExeception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException i)
        {
            System.out.println("Erorr occured while uploading file: InterruptedExecpetion");
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
        file.delete();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error occured while deleting file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fileUrl;
    }


    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }

    private String generateFileName(MultipartFile multiPart) {
        return new Date().toString().replace(" ", "-").replace(":", "_") + "-"
                + multiPart.getOriginalFilename().replace(" ", "_");
    }

    private void uploadFileTos3bucketPublicRead(String fileName, File file) {
        s3client.putObject(
                new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));

    }

    private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file));
    }  
    }
}
```

- The embedded Tomcat server of spring boot is configured to accept files smaller than 500 MB. --> so no problem here too. (please find code snippet attached too)

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5000MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=5000MB
```

- The only difference between the beanstalk environment and the localhost environment is, I can tell so far, the NGINX Proxy Server. --> Therefore I changed the nginx.conf files to allow files larger than 1 MB (since the default is 1MB) --> After this my videos with a file size smaller 57 got accepted. But still files larger than 57 MB aren't accepted (405 Status Code).
  [nginx.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jaQo.png)

All in all, I have no clue, why my files, which are larger than 57 MB aren't accepted, although I changed the client_max_body_size in (and the timeout settings) in the NGINX config files.

Also: I also tried to change my upload procedure (instead of a single putObject) to use the AWS Transfer Manager to upload small parts of the videos.

I hope I described the problem appropriately. Please do not hesitate to ask further questions.
Thank you in advance for your help!

[nginx.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS44W.png)

[postman_header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS7f7.png)

Comment: you can check the timeout's in web server

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I already changed the timeouts in the nginx.conf files as you can see in the photo. Maybe I did a mistake? 
I also looked up, that the nginx default timeout setting is 1 minute. Postman realizes uploads under 1 minute for my example video, but I still got the 405 status code.

Comment: can you share your  nginx.config file

Comment: can you check the headers the network request

Comment: You can find the photo in my post. There is a link called: nginx.conf. Or is the link not displayed?

Comment: What do you mean by "headers in the network request"?

Comment: 1) I am not able to see the any image is question
2) While you send request via postman check the header of the failed one

Comment: 1) I edited my post - I hope you can now access the photo. 2) In Postman Headers: Where should I look for?

Comment: 1) config looks good.
2) While you try to upload the file you have request and response headers in end of execution 
3) I strongly believe we have to check the load balancer only. Because default beanstalk have these settings.

Comment: 2) I put the header of postman in my post, so you can have a look. 3) Yeah, could be, I also installed a beanstalk environment with and without the Load Balancer - no difference. But maybe I have to change the settings of the Load Balancer?

Comment: May be i got the issue Can you check the S3 settings Refer [Link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=606068)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My cloudfront settings are empty. There is nothing to set up. I think, if my POST-request was not allowed, then all requests would have to blocked and not only those over 57 MB.
Its really a mystery, because on localhost everything is fine, and on beanstalk everything less than 57MB is fine too.

Comment: I think in code you're using PUT method right ?

Comment: No, I use POST method.

Comment: So you got the issue right ? (cloudfront)

Comment: No, I can't change anything in cloudfront. Still have the same problem. I also changed my method to PUT, but still not working. Thank you for your hints!

Comment: I think I fixed part of the problem. After studying the logs of my spring boot application, I noticed "java heap space", although aws was telling me in the monitoring section that there is enough capacity. I decided to increase the capacity of the ec2 instance - no 405 status code anymore. :) - Now I receive for files larger than 225 MB a 413 Entity too large error. I think I have to improve my nginx configs.

Comment: Ohh god nice see simple solution

Comment: Thank you for your support. You gave me some good hints! 
Do you know what else I have to add to my nginx config to avoid the entitiy to large error ? (I already increased the client_may_bodx_size to 5G)

Comment: i am sure about other places because Cloud providers keep on updating their environments.

Comment: Yeah you are right, my configurations are lost after some time, if the env is updated. I read about the .ebextensions for elastic beanstalk, but I sill not figured out how to integrate it into my project.